# axios react js auto-cancelling request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to use a REST API. Axios won't get my data.. The request is always cancelled. Although,i opened another app i wrote about a month ago,and it had an axios get request which worked fine.Can you see any problem in my code?
I'm using this for React js

```
import axios from 'axios'
class Results extends Component
{
    componentDidMount()
    {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",{timeout:10000}).then(response=>{console.log(response);},rejected=>{console.log(rejected)}
        )
    }
    render()
    {
        return(<div></div>);
    }
}
export default Results
```

And this is my console:[image]

Comment: You would need to add more code.
Your action and index.js

Comment: It seems like like the requests are getting timed out

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, that's 10000 timeout..it didn't... i used postman and it was working fine...and that other app,it had the default timeout and still worked

Comment: @UtsavPatel what code?

Comment: @UtsavPatel what u said didn't work... But i took ur hint about index.js and removed interceptors and it worked fine.. thank you

Comment: @UtsavPatel turns out i didn't return the response after printing it in interceptor